# Jquery. How to calculate sum of "data-" attributes from inputs, where value > 0

Tags: jquery, input, attributes, sum

Hello I need get value of data-plus attribute with Jquery
See example

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/24zr4ww5/][1]
```

I can calculate sum of all inputs, and I need get sum of data-plus all inputs, where value > 0

Comment: You should iterate your buttons with $.each

    var buttons = $('.button');
    var sum=0;
    
    $.each(buttons, function (index, item) {
        if ($(item).data('plus')>0) sum+=$(item).data('plus');  
    });

Comment: Could you explain which button you mean? 
I don't understand your idea, sorry.
Or add your code in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below way to get data value, this is the way to get data attribute

```
var value = $(this).data('field');
```

Comment: I can use a value of data-plus attribute, but I can't get it for inputs, where value > 0

Comment: Unfortunately community can't help me with finding solution.
But I did it myself
    http://jsfiddle.net/hvm4L4qr/
This simple script count all values of data-plus attribute and calculate total_result

Comment: did u get the answer or not?

Comment: yes, see link below
    http://jsfiddle.net/hvm4L4qr/

Comment: Thanks for leting us know, APpreciate